# Cannot connect to LDAP php

Tags: php, openssl, ldap

I tried to connect to an LDAP server within the company's network using php 5.2.17 and get this error for one of the php servers in IIS (Note that I have ran the script on other servers and it works just fine... so it has to do with configurations...):

```
resource(1) of type (ldap link) Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\websitename\index.php on line 13 bool(false) Can't contact LDAP server
```

I have enabled php_ldap.dll and used "putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');" and still does not work.

```
<?php 
                putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');
                $connect = ldap_connect("ldaps://example.example.com",636);
                var_dump($connect);

                $dn = "uid=1234, ou=random,o=random,c=us";

                $b = ldap_bind($connect, "$dn", "Password");

                var_dump($b);

                echo ldap_error($connect); 
>
```

I don't think there is an issue with the code since I already have it running successfully on other servers. Any help on what might be the issue (possibly configuration issues? or ssl? ) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ldap_connect with an LDAP-URI. That means the second argument is ignored. So if you want to connect to to a certain port you need to put that into the LDAP-URI like this: „ldaps://example.example.com:636“.

Apart from that: Make sure that your server actually can reach the LDAP-Server on the network-level. Sometimes corporate firewalls block connections.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have issues when I use $connect = ldap_connect("ldaps://example.example.com:636",636); . How do I determine if this server can reach LDAP - Server? Also, other servers are able to connect so I don't understand the issue.